# Polling SQL - is there any better solution?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, polling

I have to implement a functionality, where client A sends some information to the server (which stores it to an SQL db), and client B wants to retrieve that piece of information. To do so, client B calls a WCF function, which waits for the information (for a long time, until a timeout happens, or the information arrives).

What is the best practice to implement the WCF function? Polling the SQL db to query if the information is there or not? Is there any SQL DB side functionality to help?

The WCF must be written in C# (.NET CORE is preferred). The SQL server is not chosen yet, preferred MS SQL or an Azure solution, but can be other sql server which fits for the .NET CORE.

Comment: This is not a question. This is business requirement. You should research, try to do something then if you have any particular code problem, you can ask. But where is the code? I don't see any.

Comment: I am doing the research thing now. If you need some code: "while (IsInformationExists("ClientA")==false) {Thread.Sleep(100);}" is there any better solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 Event-Driven Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352703/sql-server-2008-event-driven-architecture)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at SQL Server's [Query Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot of things actually. Its more like a project management architecture related question.

You can connect your user B to a group which sends information to all its connected clients when available. You can use two of the following, there maybe more.

1. SignalR - Real time communication between server and clients
2. FireBase - By Google for real-time apps

Comment: Oh sorry. Client B don't know the location of Client A, or don't know anything about Client A. Besided, Client A is behind a firewall or something, so he can call a WCF function to retrieve information, but cannot be targeted from an external location or service. On the server side some rules must be applied before the information can be retrieved by ClientA. So an external 3rd party service is not the solution I want to use :(

Comment: No, you don't need to connect clients together directly. All clients should be connected to a Hub server which will allow server to push data to any of its connected clients.

Comment: That's ok, but I don't see how the hub server will know the information is available. That is the main question. The information is available in an SQL table.